# How to validate a string like '$Now + 2h' using regex, for JS?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, react-redux, string-parsing

I have a user input to validate:

String is made up of Part 1 + Part 2.
**Part 1** can be '$Now' or '$Today' or '$CurrentMonth'. 
**Part 1 is mandatory.**

**Part 2** can be '+' or '-' Followed by **number** and a **unit**.
Number can be any number, and Unit should be one of 'm','h','d'. 
**Part 2 is optional**

Some valid examples:

```
'$Now', 
'$Today',
'$CurrentMonth',
'$Now + 2h',
'$Now - 4m',
'$Now + 6d',
'$Today - 7d'
```

Tried several patterns but wan't able to get through as I have very little knowledge on regex.

Comment: Why do you say `#Now` in the first part of the question then say `$Now` in the second?

Comment: Sorry, that was a Typo. Edited the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
^\$(Now|Today|CurrentMonth)\s*(?:([+-])\s*(\d+)([dhm]))?\s*$
```

It looks for one of `$Now`, `$Today` or `$CurrentMonth` followed by an optional `+/-`, digits and unit (`d`, `m` or `h`). It captures `Part 1` in group 1, then the `+/-` in group 2, digits in group 3 and unit in group 4 to simplify post processing.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lfpXyR/2)